# Convert python 3.5 to an executable when nothing is working

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

Please read before marking as a duplicate

Here is what I have tried:

#### Pyinstaller:

I get the the pyi-rth qt5plugins fatal error whenever I try to run the executable. I get no warnings when actually making the program (during the second run because of all those windows crt things the first time). As far as I can tell the Qt dlls are in the folder too but because I get no warning I don't know what it thinks it is missing.

UPDATE:
So the first time I run pyinstaller I get the huge list of warnings like this

```
lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of      c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-    packages\PIL\_imaging.cp35-win32.pyd
```

Which I was told (incorrectly?) were just a result of windows having to make those temp files now and that to fix it all I have to do is run the same command again without changing anything (which did seem to work until now).

Running it the second time I get no warnings or anything but trying to run the exe gets this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "c:\users\cryan\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 573, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
Failed to execute script pyi_rth_qt5plugins
```

#### py2exe:

I get this error

```
File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\olefile\olefile2.py", line 225
    raise ValueError, 'Need to fix a bug with 32 bit arrays, please contact author...'
```

#### cx-freeze:

```
method = dis._unpack_opargs if sys.version_info[:2] >= (3, 5) \
AttributeError: module 'dis' has no attribute '_unpack_opargs'
```

So I have no idea what else to try. I would like to point out that pyinstaller was working fine a while back and since then I am pretty sure I haven't changed anything one moment I was building and running them fine and then all of a sudden I started getting the error and since then nothing has worked

What else can I try?

Comment: PyInstaller has a lot of built-in hacks to work around problems with popular 3rd part libraries. Perhaps it doesn't have all of the hacks you need. I would suggest opening an issue with PyInstaller, but you need to be much, much more specific. Include a [mcve].

Comment: I can't upload my code but with pyinstaller it seems like it must be an error with pyqt so I will update with the exact error message I get when trying to run and with the command output

Comment: *"I can't upload my code"* I didn't ask you to. No one wants to dig through all of it anyway. A [mcve] means creating a new, minimal application that demonstrates the same problem you're seeing.

Comment: Alright, okay my apologies. The smallest application that does this is any qt application. If I import from PyQt5 then I get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to solve the pyinstaller problem. Follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/How-to-Report-Bugs)

Esentially delete the following (depending on your OS):

```
%APPDATA%\pyinstaller
$XDG_DATA_HOME/pyinstaller
~/Library/Application Support/pyinstaller
```

and then install the dev version:

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with py2exe:

```
py -m pip install olefile --upgrade
```

The bug in olefile has been fixed in the latest version. Once I updated this package, the error went away.